Under what circumstances is it beneficial for an untrained native speaker to correct a non-native speaker?
I'm becoming increasingly disabused of the belief that average native speakers (i.e., untrained in teaching their native language) provide helpful feedback to students learning their language.  Often they're sharing their "head-canon" rules and definitions that don't apply universally, based on implicit rather than explicit knowledge.
To give some of my embarrassing examples:

Once when I was in Iran, I was surprised when someone said "shrine" instead of "mosque", so I "corrected" them.  But guess what?  It was a shrine and I was 100% wrong.

With one of my Chinese friends, I said "fierce" cannot be used as an adjective for "competition".  We asked genAI (it was called "Sage" at the time), and it contradicted me.  It took me quite a while to accept I was completely wrong about this.


This sort of stuff is cringeworthy, especially when I, without being asked, have derailed a conversation to make an incorrect point.  And nowadays I'm sometimes on the receiving end when learning Chinese.  So...
Question: Under what circumstances is it beneficial for an untrained native speaker to correct a non-native speaker?
I realize this question is subjective, but hopefully it counts as "good subjective", where people justify their suggested criteria.  I'm hoping for a list of questions to ask myself, or even a flowchart, to help me decide whether or not I should attempt to help, or just keep my mouth shut.  I think, given my history of "incorrect corrections", I'm going to be far more inclined to simply not say anything.

You obviously have to trust the level the native speaker has and their awareness of their own language. But ultimately, one can only be sure of what one knows oneself.

As a learner, I appreciate:

corrections on tone, or making the tone of something I said explicit
or more generally the difference between several words with similar meanings
introducing new grammatical ideas, idioms or vocabulary I did not know before.

I do not particularly appreciate:

fixing mistakes I already know of, but still commit because of lacking routine or contamination from my native language
lecturing me about those parts of grammar I know better than you, especially if you are wrong
non-constructive, negative feedback.

So please do fix issues where I am actually causing a misunderstanding, or at least check what I mean, but generally it is nicer to teach by example and continued interaction, rather than correction.
Of course, many untrained native speakers can have an intelligent discussion about language and grammar, having learnt that stuff in school and cultivated it by reading and thinking afterwards, and such a discussion might well be appreciated by both parties in the right circumstances.
